# Microsoft.FASTSearch.Powershell Snapin not available

Tags: powershell, fast-for-sharepoint, fast

On a Sharepoint 2010 Server, i tried running a script that needs to use Get-FASTSearchMetadataCategory.

`Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.FASTSearch.Powershell"` returns an error, that the snap-in is unknown. Copying the dll to the directory did not help, registering in the GAC using gacutil did not help either.

How can I enable powershell to find the `FASTSearch.powershell.dll`? Does it have to be installed during the FASTSearch Server installation? I did not set up the system, so someone may have opted to not install this. I also never installed FAST, so I have no experience with the setup process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FAST commandlets are only available on a server which has FS4SP installed. And they are installed during the installation of FS4SP. There's even a management shell which preloads the snap-in.

Comment: Your answer is correct. When I finally got hold of the infrastructure guys behind the server i tried to run the script on, they explained that FAST isn't even installed there. Someone had told me otherwise, and I only had restricted access.